# Why doesn't the \closing center in my letter?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, pdftex, letters

If I `pdflatex` the below Latex, then "Kind regards," and "Sandra" doesn't get centred.

If the letter is two pages long, then it does.

**Question**

How do I get this centred when my letter is just one page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, danish]{letter}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{aeguill}

\signature{Sandra}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Re: }

test

\closing{Kind regards,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those are not usually centered, but you could surround them in the `center` environment: `\begin{center}
\closing{Kind regards,}
\end{center}`.

Comment: You could also just end `letter` with `\centering Kind regards,\par\vskip{5\baselineskip} Sandra`.

Comment: Even with two pages, I do not see any centering. As the content produced by `\closing` is inside a `\parbox` (that is `\raggedright`), neither the `center` environment (@PeterGrill) nor the `\centering` macro actually center the text horizontally. On that note, `{\centering\closing{\centering Kind regards}}` centers the actual text inside the `\parbox` and the `\parbox` as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Good point. I did not look carefully enough and indeed it is _not_ cnetered with `\begin{center}`, but it is also not centered using `\closing{\centering Kind regards}`.  I think the `\closing` macro needs to be redefined.

Comment: Can you provide a pair of MWE that shows the multipage letter with the closing centered. If I add `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\lipsum[1-20]` to your MWE, the closing stays in the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closing isn't never centered, but it will change its location and move more to the middle if you add a "fromaddress" with `\address{fromadress}`.

The `letter`-class is quite old and not very good. Consider to use a better one:
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-letterclass

Avoid the `a4` and the `aeguill` packages.

Comment: Is the `letter` class any older than the `article` class?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Yes, I removed the `\address{}` to make it fit one page =) Thanks for pin pointing the problem. How would you have made my example?